# Matlab Image Display

Tags: matlab

Below is a function I wrote in Matlab. The function works correctly but the output displays three different images of different outputs.

```
function Img = power_Law(Img)
temp = Img;
[a,b]=size(Img);
C=0.2;
omega=0.2;
for i=1:a
    for j=1:b
        img(i,j)=C*power(temp(i,j),omega);
    end
end
imshow(img);
end
```

My Question is am I missing any conversions? Why wouldn't the output be a single Image. 
Here is a link of the output. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6vuhzodk29qaul/image.png

Comment: Is Img the one on the top, and you only call power_Law once?

Comment: I passed it the top image and only called power_Law once.

Comment: it's not a solution but you do not need to use for loops: img = C*temp.^omega; is fine here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will notice that in Matlab and Octave operation performed for matrices are dramatically faster comparing to loops over their elements. Also loops will create a possibility to make a mistake.

Let say `Img` is of size 900x1200x3, then `img` will be of size 900x3600 because `[a,b]=size(img)` returns `a =  900`, `b =  3600` as `Img` is three dimensional array.
Then proper code will look something like this, note it doesn't change dimensionality of `img2`

```
function img2 = power_law(img, C, omega)
  img2 = C * power(img, omega);
  imshow(img2);
end
```